# GoLang github get new client with oauth2 by using persona access token (API TOKEN)

Tags: go

I am trying to list repos by using following simple code, It gives 403 bad credentials error, I think the problem is that I have custom Github Url https://github.mycompany.io
Can someone suggest how I can solve this since i am quite new to Go.

```
import(
 "golang.org/x/oauth2"
 "github.com/google/go-github/github"
)
func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    ts := oauth2.StaticTokenSource(
        &oauth2.Token{AccessToken: "MY GITHUB STATIC TOKEN"},
    )
    tc := oauth2.NewClient(ctx, ts)

    client := github.NewClient(tc)

    //list all repositories for the authenticated user
    repos, _, err := client.Repositories.List(ctx, "", nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using a hosted github have you tried `NewEnterpriseClient()`?

see https://github.com/google/go-github/blob/f5943dbb9a7a560d3894701dbe3481f81886393a/github/github_test.go#L269